# how to call webservice from java

Tags: java, web-services, call

I have to write a simple application that calls a web-service from android. So please give me a sample code to call it. And please it will be better if the code does not use any special libraries which I have to download and include in project. Also that code should not use the word "Soap" because I have searched a lot on net and every where there is example given "how to call Soap web service". I don't have to call a Soap or anything else, just a simple web service. So please give a reference code or at-least some useful links.
Now I tried a code,

```
public class TriongleJava {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://vogellac2dm.appspot.com/register");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationid", "123456789"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

but its giving error,

> HttpClient , DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost , NameValuePair etc can not be resolved.

How to remove those errors

Comment: what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: You could try solving those errors, reading them and tracing their origins, and thinking about it.  Or even posting them here.  Those kinds of problems are answerable and fit for this website.

Comment: @bdares yes, I have tried it, searched a lot on net, but not able to solve those errors. That's why I came here(on this site)

Comment: My recommendation would get to do a basic Java programming tutorial.  Pay attention to the bit about the `import` statement.  Then go back to wherever you copied that code from and **read** the context ... which should tell you what you need to import (if it is any good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks mostly workable.

The errors you're getting are because you're using external classes.  These classes are defined in libraries.  Some, such as `BufferedReader` are included in the standard java library and can be simply included using

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

I'm assuming the others you are trying to use are from the Apache HTTP client library.  You can download the files [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and include them in your classpath before importing the relevant classes.

Answer (score 2):

To call a web service, you need to agree on a communication protocol which may be SOAP, POST, XML etc.

If you want to call using POST protocol then you may use the following link:
[POST Example](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

Comment: I'm getting error HttpClient, DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost, BasicNameValuePair, HttpResponse, ClientProtocolException etc can not be resolved. How to remove those errors?

Comment: Seems like you're missing the required imports try including:  `import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;  
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;  
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;  
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;`

Answer (score 1):

Use any java library which can make http call. 
Can refer to this link http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html

Comment: I'm getting error UrlEncodedFormEntity, HttpClient, DefaultHttpClient, HttpPost, BasicNameValuePair, HttpResponse, ClientProtocolException etc can not be resolved. How to remove those errors?